# how can i git clone git://foo.git AGAIN?

Tags: git, clone

I did
 git clone git://foo.git
 cd foo
 ...edit files..

now I want to start fresh. I don't care about any changes I already made,
but I don't want to clone the whole giant foo.git again, just lose all my changes.
how can i git clone git://foo.git   a second time, without getting

`fatal: destination path 'foo' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

what is the proper command?

Answer (score 10):

```
git checkout . # revert your changes
git clean -xdf # delete untracked and ignored files
```

Comment: Nice ~! I didn't know about `clean`!

Comment: Note: git checkout . obviously will not work if you are not in the top of your repo. `git reset --hard` will work universally.

Answer (score 2):

To revert all your changes, use:

```
git checkout .
```

Untracked files (files that didn't originally exist in the tree, ones you created and not edited) will not be removed, though. To find the untracked files, use:

```
git status
```

Then delete them manually.

By the way, if you'd like to make a copy of the repo, you don't need to clone the original repo, you can simply clone the one you already have on your hard disk. Go somewhere outside `foo`, and do:

```
git clone /path/to/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "git checkout ." or "git checkout HEAD -- .", or even "git reset --hard HEAD" to reset your working area to known state (to state recorded in index in first case, to state recorded in HEAD commit in second and third case).

To delete untracked files you don't want to keep you can use "git clean" (see [documentation for details](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html)).

To get new changes from remote repository you cloned from, use "git fetch" (or equivalent "git remote update", after some setup), or "git pull" (to fetch *and* merge changes).

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* screw it up:

```
git clean -df
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also always use

```
rm -rf *
git checkout master
```

Less commands to remember :)

Comment: That doesn't work if master already contains local commits since they will still be there.